# Export MySQL table using order by

Tags: mysql

How do I export a MySQL table in the format such as the below?  Looking to save a .sql file exported in order of event_start_date.

```
SELECT * FROM `wp_events`
ORDER BY `wp_events`.`event_start_date` ASC
```

Comment: Can you explain why you need this? When you import the sql in the database again you can order it as you like.

Comment: if you use phpmyadmin, you can use SQL tab. Run your SQL there, and then you will see results, then you can use EXPORT button under the results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [OUTFILE clause](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html)?

```
SELECT * FROM `wp_events`
ORDER BY `wp_events`.`event_start_date` ASC
mysqlmysqldump
INTO OUTFILE 'file_name'  -- this bit
```

Note: if this data is intended to be reimported, note that a table has no inherent order